# Dropbox API v2 - uploading files

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I'm trying to loop through a folder structure in python and upload each file it finds to a specified folder. The problem is that it's uploading a file with the correct name, however there is no content and the file size is only 10 bytes.

```
import dropbox, sys, os
try:
  dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('some_access_token')
  user = dbx.users_get_current_account()
except:
  print ("Negative, Ghostrider")
  sys.exit()

rootdir = os.getcwd()

print ("Attempting to upload...")
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
      for file in files:
        try:  
          dbx.files_upload("afolder",'/bfolder/' + file, mute=True)
          print("Uploaded " + file)
        except:
          print("Failed to upload " + file)
print("Finished upload.")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your call to `dbx.files_upload("afolder",'/bfolder/' + file, mute=True)` says: "Send the text `afolder` and write it as a file named `'/bfolder/' + file`".

#### From [doc](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.org/en/master/moduledoc.html#dropbox.base.DropboxBase.files_upload):

> *files_upload(f, path, mode=WriteMode('add', None), autorename=False, client_modified=None, mute=False)*
>   Create a new file with the contents provided in the request.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - f – A string or file-like obj of data.
> - path (str) – Path in the user’s Dropbox to save the file.
>     ....

Meaning that `f` must be the **content of the file** (and not the filename string).

#### Here is a working example:

```
import dropbox, sys, os

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('token')
rootdir = '/tmp/test' 

print ("Attempting to upload...")
# walk return first the current folder that it walk, then tuples of dirs and files not "subdir, dirs, files"
for dir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        try:
            file_path = os.path.join(dir, file)
            dest_path = os.path.join('/test', file)
            print 'Uploading %s to %s' % (file_path, dest_path)
            with open(file_path) as f:
                dbx.files_upload(f, dest_path, mute=True)
        except Exception as err:
            print("Failed to upload %s\n%s" % (file, err))

print("Finished upload.")
```

**EDIT: For Python3 the following should be used:**

`dbx.files_upload(f.read(), dest_path, mute=True)`

Comment: Thanks for that. I was looking at the example for the Python SDK on the Dropbox API v2 page, it's a little misleading. I should've gone straight to the docs!

Comment: @MikeResoli What specifically were you looking at that misled you? We'd love to take the opportunity to improve the website.

Comment: @smarx it was on this page, but now I look back I realise I look dumb: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python#tutorial

`dbx.files_upload("Potential headline: Game 5 a nail-biter as Warriors inch out Cavs", '/cavs vs warriors/game 5/story.txt')` I presumed the first argument was a sort of description tag for the upload.

Comment: @MikeResoli Thanks! Maybe it would be clearer if the first argument was something like "Hello, World!"

Comment: I think it would be clearer to show a file instance instead of a string. Or a self descripting string like "File content to send".

Comment: @smarx Thanks for getting back to me, it's great to see Dropbox wanting to improve customer experience. I agree with though, a description string would fit better as he suggested.

Comment: not to bother people, this same issue of string or file like object `f` led me to this thread, thanks @Cyrbil for the example.

Comment: You should read bytes to avoid errors. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41286747/8205554

Answer (score 1):

For Dropbox Business API below python code helps uploading files to dropbox.

#function code

import dropbox

def dropbox_file_upload(access_token,dropbox_file_path,local_file_name):

```
'''
The function upload file to dropbox.

    Parameters:
        access_token(str): Access token to authinticate dropbox
        dropbox_file_path(str): dropboth file path along with file name
        Eg: '/ab/Input/f_name.xlsx'
        local_file_name(str): local file name with path from where file needs to be uploaded
        Eg: 'f_name.xlsx' # if working directory
Returns:
    Boolean: 
        True on successful upload
        False on unsuccessful upload
'''
try:
    dbx = dropbox.DropboxTeam(access_token)
    # get the team member id for common user
    members = dbx.team_members_list()
    for i in range(0,len(members.members)):
        if members.members[i].profile.name.display_name == logged_in_user:
            member_id = members.members[i].profile.team_member_id
            break
    # connect to dropbox with member id
    dbx = dropbox.DropboxTeam(access_token).as_user(member_id)
    # upload local file to dropbox
    f = open(local_file_name, 'rb')
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(),dropbox_file_path)
    return True
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return False
```