# Dropbox API v2 - trying to upload file with files_upload() - throws TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have been trying to upload a simple file to dropbox using the files_upload() function in python3

Even trying out the code in the [tutorial provided on Dropbox's site](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python#tutorial) I get an error and I don't understand why. What am I missing here?

**Here is my code:**

```
import dropbox

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("my_access_token")

data = "asd"

dbx.files_upload(data, '/file.txt')
```

**And here is the error message I get when I try to run it:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dbox.py", line 7, in <module>
    dbx.files_upload(data, '/file.txt')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dropbox/base.py", line 1225, in files_upload
    f,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 249, in request
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 341, in request_json_string_with_retry
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 385, in request_json_string
    type(request_binary))
TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class 'str'>
```

**I've tried it different ways:**

**1.**

```
with open("/home/pi/Desktop/dbox/asd.txt", "rb") as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f, '/asd.txt', mute = True)
```

**2.**

```
dbx.files_upload("hello", "")
```

**3.**

```
dbx.files_upload("hello", "/")
```

but I get the same error every time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [this](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_upload) documentation, it appears that the first argument to `files_upload()` needs to be a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) object. Which means you got close with:

```
with open("/home/pi/Desktop/dbox/asd.txt", "rb") as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f, '/asd.txt', mute = True)
```

Try this instead (`f.read()` returns a `bytes` object):

```
with open("/home/pi/Desktop/dbox/asd.txt", "rb") as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), '/asd.txt', mute = True)
```

You could also try passing `data.encode(whatever_encoding)` instead of just `data`. I am not sure why this is not mentioned in the tutorial that you linked.