# Dropbox API - trying to upload a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dropbox-api

I've just rebuilt my Raspberry Pi and hence installed the latest version of the Dropbox API and now my program doesn't work.  I think this is due to point 1 in these breaking changes: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/releases/tag/v7.1.0. I'm sure this question from SO ([Dropbox API v2 - trying to upload file with files_upload() - throws TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285969/dropbox-api-v2-trying-to-upload-file-with-files-upload-throws-typeerror/41286747)) solves my problem... but as a newbie, I can't figure out how to actually implement it - and anyway, I'm already using `f.read()`... can anyone help?

This is my code:

```
def DropboxUpload(file):
    sourcefile = "/home/pi/Documents/iot_pm2/dropbox_transfer/" + filename
    targetfile = "/" + filename
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(cfg.dropboxtoken)
    f = open(sourcefile, "r")
    filecontents = f.read()
    try:
        dbx.files_upload(filecontents, targetfile, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)
    except dropbox.exceptions.ApiError as err:
        print(err)
    f.close()
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/iot_pm2/dropbox_uploader.py", line 20, in <module>
    DropboxUpload(filename)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/iot_pm2/dropbox_uploader.py", line 12, in DropboxUpload
    dbx.files_upload(filecontents, targetfile, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dropbox/base.py", line 2125, in files_upload
    f,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 272, in request
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 363, in request_json_string_with_retry
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 407, in request_json_string
    type(request_binary))
TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class 'str'>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply `bytes`, but you're supplying `str`.

You can get `bytes` by changing the file mode to binary. I.e., instead of:

```
f = open(sourcefile, "r")
```

do:

```
f = open(sourcefile, "rb")
```